# Android using JSON Error : "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value "

Tags: java, android, json

I have this code that i used it in local host to display a listView when I upload it ,nothing is displayed in my ListView. So this what i did. Normally i get all data saved in my database but the screen is empty.

```
 private ListView listView;
 public static final String    URL="http://gabes.comlu.com/Base_Controle/getAllEmp.php";
// static String TAG_JSON_ARRAY="";
 private String JSON_STRING;
 static JSONObject result = null;
 public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY = "result";

   private void showEmployee(){
       JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
                JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String nom1 = jo.getString("nom");
                String tele1 = jo.getString("tele");
                String grade1 = jo.getString("grade");
                String image1 = jo.getString("image");
                String site1 = jo.getString("site");
                String email1 = jo.getString("email");
                HashMap<String,String> employees = new HashMap<>();
                // employees.put("Type",type);
                employees.put("log",nom1);
                employees.put("a",tele1);
                employees.put("pre",grade1);
                employees.put("d",image1);
                employees.put("c",site1);
                employees.put("b", email1);
                list.add(employees);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(), list, R.layout.list_item1,
                new String[]{"log","pre","a","b","c","d"},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name,R.id.a});

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: post your logcat and json

Comment: Please post your json and your stacktrace!

Comment: You didn't get the json from the web?

Comment: I checked your response. i did not see any "result" json array.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON_ARRAY constant has no value:

```
static String TAG_JSON_ARRAY="";
```

You are trying to get a `JSONArray` with an empty tag and this is why you get an `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this json data using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library.

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<test>>() {
    }.getType();
    ArrayList<test> Data = (ArrayList<test>) gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```

Here Test is class of your json data :

```
public class test {

String nom;
String add;
String tele;


public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public String getAdd() {
    return add;
}

public void setAdd(String add) {
    this.add = add;
}

public String getTele() {
    return tele;
}

public void setTele(String tele) {
    this.tele = tele;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all :)
I solved the problem by editing this :

```
private String JSON_STRING;
static JSONObject result = null;
......
 try {
                JSONArray result = new JSONArray(json);
            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
}
 protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();

                JSON_STRING = s;
                showEmployee(s);
            }
```